# Beamer. Configuring the section with \renewcommand

Tags: beamer, sectioning

In a document using the beamer class, I would like to replace the section numbers by an indication such as "Step", which will obviously have to appear in the table of contents (tableofcontents).
Here's what I'd like to have:

**Step one. First Section**

Any text

**Step 2. Second Section**

Any text

I tried `\renewcommand{\thesection}{Step \arabic{section}.}` : it works with any class (`article`, `scrartcl`), but never with `beamer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the `section in toc` template to add whatever text you like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
  \leavevmode%
  % prevents the period to be printed with the first/last section option
  \ifnum\beamer@tempcount>\beamer@toclastsection
  \else
  \ifnum\beamer@tempcount>0
    Step~\inserttocsectionnumber.
  \fi\fi%
  \inserttocsection\par%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]